# "Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object on computer '<remote hyper-v server' because the object was not found."

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, windows-server-core, winrm

Setting up a Windows 8.1 Enterprise VM with Hyper-V tools installed to manage our Hyper-V Servers. I have it working with one hypervisor already, but on this one I get the above error. I have followed the usual install; add machines to hosts file on either side, make a local admin on the hypervisor that matches the admin on the client, set the WSMan TrustedHosts list on both sides. I can see the hypervisor in Server manager and it reports everything is good but I tried to make an SMB share (just to test functionality) and got a WinRM error. I have attempted to completely turn off the firewall by setting all profiles to off, which didn't work. I've set these Windows 8.1 management machines up dozens of times and have never run into this issue before.

I have 5-nine on the hypervisor and that works just fine. The VMMS service is definitely running, and there is a VM already running on the machine (which is why I haven't rebooted it... it's critical for daily operation)

I'm thinking it must be an issue with WinRM but I'm not sure in which direction to head for a solution

Comment: Check this link to create SMB share https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134187(v=ws.11).aspx